# How to count the lines containing one of two words but not both

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep

I need to count the lines containing the words `the` and `an` in a text file (`poem.txt`), but *not those containing both*.

I've tried using

```
grep -c the poem.txt | grep -c an poem.txt
```

but this gives me the wrong answer of 6 when the total number of `the` and `an` is 9 lines.

I do want to count the lines containing the words and not the words themselves. Only the actual word should count, so `the` but not `there`, and `an` but not `Pan`.

Example file: `poem.txt`

```
Where is the misty shark?
Where is she?
The small reef roughly fights the mast.
Where is the small gull?
Where is he?
The gull grows like a clear pirate.
Clouds fall like old mainlands.

She will Rise calmly like a dead pirate.
Eat an orange.
Warm, sunny sharks quietly pull a cold, old breeze.
All ships command rough, rainy sails.

Elvis Aaron Presley also known simply as the Elvis
He is also referred to as the King
The best-selling solo music artist of all time
He was the most commercially successful artist in many genres

He has many awards including a Grammy lifetime achievement
Elvis in the 1970s has numerous jumpsuits including an eagle one.
```

To clarify further: how many lines in the poem contain  `the` or `an` but you should not count the lines that include both `the` and `an`.

```
the car is red - this counted
an apple is in the corner - not counted
hello i am big - not counted
where is an apple - counted
```

So here the output should be 2.

Edit: I'm not worried about case sensitivity.

[image: screenshot of highlighted words]

Final edit: Thanks for all your help.
i've managed to solve the problem. i used the one of the answer and changed it a little. i used
 `cat poem.txt   | grep -Evi -e '\<an .* the\>' -e '\<the .* an\>'   | grep -Eci -e '\<(an|the)\>` how ever i did change the `-c` in the second grep to a `-n` for some added info.
Yet again thank you for all the help!! :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and i) add an example input file and ii) show the output you expect. Clarify if we should count `pan` as an occurrence of `an` or not. Also clarify if you want to count the lines or the number of times each word appears.

Comment: Does "but not both" mean a line that contains both should not count at all? Or should it add 1 to the count (as opposed to adding 2)?

Comment: `grep -c the poem.txt | grep -c an poem.txt` does not what you expect. It first counts the number of lines with *the*. The output, i.e. the number, is piped into a second grep, which ignores its input. It counts the lines containing *an* and outputs that. Besides, the two `grep` commands also count lines that contain *there* or *demand*.

Comment: What about two occuences of the word? (e.g. `The` & `the` on line 3) How about case sensitivity?

Comment: Is `best-selling` one word or 2 (or even 3 - best, selling, and best-selling)? As always with these sorts of questions the definition of a "word" is key.

Comment: Nice. In GNU grep 3.4, I found that I can omit `\<` and `\>`  like so:  


`cat poem.txt   | grep -Evi -e 'an .* the' -e 'the.* an'   | grep -Eci -e '(an|the)'`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With grep:

```bsh
cat poem.txt \
  | grep -Evi -e '\<an\>.*\<the\>' -e '\<the\>.*\<an\>' \
  | grep -Eci -e '\<(an|the)\>'
```

**This counts the *matched lines*. You can find an alternative syntax which counts the total number of *matches* down below.**

**Breakdown:**

The frist grep command filters out all lines containing both 'an' and 'the'. The second grep command counts those lines, containing either 'an' or 'the'.

If you remove the `c` from the second grep's `-Eci`, you will see all matches highlighted.

**Details:**

- The `-E` option enables extended expression syntax (ERE) for grep.
- The `-i` option tells grep to match case-insensitive
- The `-v` option tells grep to invert the result (i.e. match lines *not* containing the pattern)
- The `-c` option tells grep to output the number of matched lines instead of the lines themselves
- The patterns:

  1. `\<` matches the beginning of a word (thanks [@glenn-jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman))
  2. `\>` matches the end of a word (thanks [@glenn-jackman](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/4667/glenn-jackman))

  --> That way we can make sure to not match words *containing* 'the' or 'an' (like 'pan')

  3. `grep -Evi -e '\<an\>.*\<the\>'` thus matches all lines *not* containing 'an ... the'
  4. Similarly, `grep -Evi -e '\<the\>.*\<an\>'` matches all lines *not* containing 'the ... an'
  5. `grep -Evi -e '\<an\>.*\<the\>' -e '\<the.*an\>'` is the combination of the 3. and 4.
  6. `grep -Eci -e '\<(an|the)\>'` matches all lines containing either 'an' or 'the' (surrounded by whitespace or start/end of line) and prints the number of matched lines

**EDIT 1:** Use `\<` and `\>` instead of `( |^)` and `( |$)`, as suggested by @glenn-jackman

**EDIT 2:** In order to count the number of matches instead of the number of matched lines, use the following expression:

```bsh
cat poem.txt \
  | grep -Evi -e '\<an\>.*\<the\>' -e '\<the\>.*\<an\>' \
  | grep -Eio -e '\<(an|the)\>' \
  | wc -l
```

This uses the `-o` option of grep, which prints every match in a separate line (and nothing else) and then `wc -l` to count the lines.

Comment: I'd recommend using `\<` instead of `(^| )` and `\>` instead of `( |$)` -- the angle brackets are the word boundaries for [GNU extended regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/egrep-regular-expression-syntax.html). After all, a non-word character can be something different from space.

Comment: Also why use cat why not filename with grep?

Comment: i tried using this, to see whether it would work, and it does, however it prints the answer as "9", when if you remove the "c" from the second grep to print the file, and you count the highlighted words you count 10

Comment: @CookiePatriot It count's the number of lines, not the occurence of the words, as originally requested in the question

Comment: @Prvt_Yadav I felt, that it made the statement more clear. Just personal preference :)

Comment: @glennjackman Thanks! Didn't know about word boundary expressions. That's really useful! And yes, spaces are a simplification, of course. I even thought about including a larger character class manually, but it would have made the expression harder to understand. Word boundaries are perfect

Comment: @CookiePatriot I've added an alternative syntax which counts the matches, not the matched lines.

Comment: I prefer this as the OP seems more.familiar with grep than awk, and may have hoped for, or be more at ease with, a grep based answer

Comment: It gives a wrong result. Try the following text `the the\nan\nthe an\nasdfasd asdf asd asdf aan\nthey were` (`\n` - new line).

Comment: @theCalcaholic apart from being slower, with `cat` you also lose all line number information

Comment: @TigerTV.ru Your example gives 3 matches, which is correct according to the question (`the the` should not be excluded, if that's what you were referring to)

Comment: @phuclv Sure, if speed is an issue for your use case, feel free to read the file directly with grep. For the sake of readability I prefer to keep cat for my example above, though.

Regarding line numbers: I don't see how that applies, especially, since the second grep reads from stdin anyways.

Comment: @theCalcaholic, that's all right. I used your second edit code, it gives another result.

Answer (score 10):

```
perl -nE 'END {say $c+0} ++$c if /\bthe\b/i xor /\ban\b/i' file
```

```
gawk 'END {print c+0} /\<the\>/ != /\<an\>/ {++c}' IGNORECASE=1 file
```

Comparing the results from matching each expression can give the outcome you want.

For example, the result of matching `\<the\>` may be either 0 or 1. If the result of the other match is the same, then both regexps were either found or not found, and the line should not be counted. If they differ it means that one match was found and the other was not, so the counter is incremented.

gawk has a built-in `xor()` function:

```
gawk 'END {print c+0} xor(/\<the\>/,/\<an\>/) {++c}' IGNORECASE=1 file
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119376/discussion-on-answer-by-rowboat-how-to-count-the-lines-containing-one-of-two-wor).

Comment: It is interesting to note that the POSIX spec requires that the result of a regex match in awk evaluates to `1` (not other true value nor an non-empty string): [*If the regular expression matches the string, the '˜' expression shall evaluate to a value of 1, and the "!˜" expression shall evaluate to a value of 0.*](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html). Gawk also follows that convention. That's why `/.../ != /.../` results in either 0 or 1 (only true or false).

Answer (score 6):

The following GNU `awk` program should do the trick:

```
awk '(/(^|\W)[Tt]he(\W|$)/ && !/(^|\W)[Aa]n(\W|$)/) || (/(^|\W)[Aa]n(\W|$)/ && !/(^|\W)[Tt]he(\W|$)/) {c++} END{print c}' poem.txt
```

This will increase the counter `c`, if either

- the line matches `(^|\W)[Tt]he(\W|$)` (first-letter-case-insensitive `the`, preceded by non-word constituent (`\W`) or begin of line (`^`), and followed by non-word constituent (`\W`) or end-of line (`$`)) but not `(^|\W)[Aa]n(\W|$)` (the isolated first-letter-case-insensitive `an`) - OR -
- the line matches `(^|\W)[Aa]n(\W|$)` but not `(^|\W)[Tt]he(\W|$)`

In the end, print the value of `c`.

It can be formulated slightly shorter using `\<` and `\>` for "beginning-of-word" and "end-of-word":

```
awk '(/\<[Tt]he\>/ && !/\<[Aa]n\>/) || (/\<[Aa]n\>/ && !/\<[Tt]he\>/) {c++} END{print c}' poem.txt
```

Even shorter would be:

```
awk '/\<[Tt]he\>/ != /\<[Aa]n\>/ {c++} END{print c}' poem.txt
```

as the inequality is only ever true if either, but not both (nor none) of `an` and `the` are present on a line.

This approach requires GNU `awk` because the `\W` and `\<` / `\>` constructs are GNU extensions to the extended regular expression syntax (but `\<` / `\>` are also understood by [BSD regexes](https://man.openbsd.org/re_format.7)).

Notice that the pipeline construct you showed in your own attempted solution won't work, as calling `grep` with a file as input parameter supersedes reading from stdin, so the first part of the pipeline would simply vanish unnoticed, with the output being entirely due to the last part (which looks for occurences of `an`, even those embedded in other words).

Answer (score 4):

This will let you output lines containing any number of any set of words and will work using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    FS = "[^[:alnum:]_]+"
    split(tolower(tgts),tmp)
    for (i in tmp) {
        targets[tmp[i]]
    }
    tgtsRequired = (tgtsRequired ? tgtsRequired : 1)
}
{
    delete present
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        present[tolower($i)]
    }

    tgtsPresent = 0
    for (target in targets) {
        tgtsPresent += (target in present ? 1 : 0)
    }
}
tgtsPresent == tgtsRequired
```

```
$ awk -v tgts='the an' -f tst.awk poem.txt
Where is the misty shark?
The small reef roughly fights the mast.
Where is the small gull?
The gull grows like a clear pirate.
Eat an orange.
Elvis Aaron Presley also known simply as the Elvis
He is also referred to as the King
The best-selling solo music artist of all time
He was the most commercially successful artist in many genres
```

```
$ awk -v tgts='the an' -v tgtsRequired=2 -f tst.awk poem.txt
Elvis in the 1970s has numerous jumpsuits including an eagle one.
```

```
$ awk -v tgts='the an eagle' -v tgtsRequired=2 -f tst.awk poem.txt
```

```
$ awk -v tgts='the an eagle' -v tgtsRequired=3 -f tst.awk poem.txt
Elvis in the 1970s has numerous jumpsuits including an eagle one.
```

It assumes a "word" is any contiguous string of alpha-numeric-or-underscore characters.

Comment: I see you also got the causal drive-by downvote without explanation ...

Comment: @AdminBee yeah, I get one on most posts. I flagged one for moderator attention one time but nothing changed.

Comment: @terdon can you see who the phantom-of-the-forum is who runs around downvoting everything for no reason and, if so, is there anything can be done about it?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with GNU grep and PCRE zero-length assertions:

```
grep -iP '(?=.*\bthe\b)(?!.*\ban\b)|(?=.*\ban\b)(?!.*\bthe\b)' poem.txt

Where is the misty shark?
...
Eat an orange.
...

grep -ciP '(?=.*\bthe\b)(?!.*\ban\b)|(?=.*\ban\b)(?!.*\bthe\b)' poem.txt

9
```

The same feature is available in perl (where it originated), and perl may be present on machines where GNU grep isn't.

Answer (score 2):

This GNU awk command will do what you need:

```
$ awk '
        function lnxor(a,b) {return !(a&&b||(!a&&!b))};
        { str=tolower($0); a=(str~/\<the\>/); b=(str~/\<an\>/); 
          c=lnxor(a,b); count+=c 
        } END {print count}
' poem.txt

9
```

The lnxor is the **l**ogical **n**ot **xor** of `a` and `b`.

Where `a` is true if the line contains `the` and b is true if the line contains `an`.

In this way it is quite easy to extend the idea to more words.

In GNU awk it is also possible to use `IGNORECASE` (set it to non-zero), instead of `tolower()`, to ignore the case of the string being matched by the regex. However, that will change **all** string and regex operations, including the effects of FS and RS. Being, as it is, such an extensive change (which will work in this case), it should be used with more care. It is not specific to some particular test.

Answer (score 2):

A method using `perl` wherein we sum the boolean values of the regexes and using that as an index select from an anonymous array the appropriate increment depending on whether none found, any one found, or both.

```
perl -lne '$k += (0,1,0)[/\ban\b/i+/\bthe\b/i]}{print 0+$k' poems.txt
9
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `gawk` and `wc`:

```bsh
gawk 'xor(/\<an\>/,/\<the\>/)' IGNORECASE=1 ./poem.txt | wc -l
```

Comment: It bears mentioning that this requires GNU Awk, as both the `xor()` function and the `IGNORECASE` variable are not provided natively by some other implementations, notably [The One True Awk](http://github.com/onetrueawk/awk).

Comment: @GregA.Woods, yes, I used GNU Awk.

Comment: The `\<` and `\>` are also non-POSIX extensions.

Comment: @EdMorton, it's time to update POSIX :)

Comment: Then you'd have to update all of the software that claims to be POSIX compliant :-). It's easier just to say "using GNU awk for ...." in answers so people don't waste their time trying to make a script work when all they have is a POSIX awk.

Comment: @EdMorton, no, we just update a version. Does the change break previous versions of POSIX? :) The answer is updated.